# Armature modifier deforming mesh slightly

Tags: modifiers, armature, vertex-groups

Whenever I add a Armature modifier to my models, the mesh for the arm and legs shift, but just a little bit.

When I uncheck the *Bind to vertex groups* box, it restores to it's normal position but as soon as I check it again it shifts.

Not binded: 
[image]

Binded:
[image]

I know there's barely a difference but I've worked too hard on this model to and I can't let there be a mistake like this. The mesh for sure shifts every time I check vertex groups on.

Comment: It's hard to say without checking the file, but usually, when I encountered similar situation, it was because wrong alignment of controlling and deforming bones. It causes bones to move a little in pose mode from it's initial position, so check it out.

Comment: @Mzidare thank you for your input but I fixed the bone roll for the Metarig before hitting "Rigify" for all bones. Provide me a email address or something and I'll share the Dropbox link with you when I get home as long as you promise not to share the link or the .Blend file. I am taking these precautions because I worked very hard on this model.

Comment: It sounds like an issue caused by IKs with wrong poles. Without further information this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 1):

In blender 2.8+ there is a new *Save as Shape Key* which keeps the modifier in the stack and allows you to config the shape key to have the power of -1.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do this? Perhaps describe the steps and show some screenshots of the results

Answer (score 0):

So I have (Kind of?) found a way to fix this issue using Shape Keys, but it's very impractical. First you apply armature modifier as Shape Key with bind to vertex groups box checked on then you go to Shape Key and set the range's minimum value to -1.00. So now when you add a new armature modifier the mesh expands to it's original position because of the -1.00 Shape Key range value.
Unfixed:[image]

Fixed:
[image]

I had to zoom in really close to the mesh so you guys could see the difference. Could someone please please PLEASE tell me a way to avoid this problem all together without going through all that hassle?

Comment: This strategy adds a bit of lag also so if someone could find an alternative that would be great.